# Change Checkbox Form Controls in a group

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

There are six Forms checkboxes that had been "grouped" and named app_list.

There are individual Forms checkboxes in the entire **Worksheet**

When I run this macro that I found online:

```
Sub ClearFormsCheckboxes()
Dim chBox As CheckBox
For Each chBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If chBox.Value = 1 Then
        chBox.Value = 0
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

...the individual checkboxes gets unchecked but the group "app_list" remains unchanged. I've been thinking of just doing an ungroup - uncheck - regroup method but that seems too much.

There has to be something I can do to change the value of the entire group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few remarks first:

1. Always use `Option Explicit`. It makes the declaring of variables mandatory and saves you from mistakes
2. Avoid using `ActiveSheet`. Instead refer to the worksheet explicitly
3. When you group a few `checkboxes` you basically create a `shape`. The members of the group belong to the `.GroupItems` collection and they are `shapes` as well.

The following should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearFormsCheckboxes()

Dim chBox As CheckBox
Dim groupedChBox As Shape
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Use the name of the sheet where the checkboxes are located

For Each chBox In sht.CheckBoxes 'non grouped checkboxes
    If chBox.Value = 1 Then
        chBox.Value = 0
    End If
Next chBox

For Each groupedChBox In sht.Shapes("Group 1").GroupItems 'Grouped checkboxes. Use the name of the group
    If groupedChBox.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
        groupedChBox.ControlFormat.Value = 0
    End If
Next groupedChBox

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Stavros. Especially for the added pointers. Really helped!